# LibreOffice Calc macro - How to remove header and footer in given sheet?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

Default header and footer show up when I print out invoice created by macro.
I want to remove them in my macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this is the way to turn header and footer off:

```
Dim oDoc As Object
Dim oSheet As Object
Dim oStyles As Variant
Dim oPstyle As Variant

oDoc=ThisComponent

oSheet=oDoc.Sheets.getByName("Sheet1")

oStyles=oDoc.StyleFamilies.getByName("PageStyles")
oPstyle=oStyles.getByName(oSheet.PageStyle)
oPstyle.HeaderOn=FALSE
oPstyle.FooterOn=FALSE
```